# How do I prevent code written in my <pre> from rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, pretty-print, prettify

So I am using the google code prettifier: http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/

It does something similar to what stack overflow does here where when you write a block of code it beautifies it and adds syntax highlighting.

The problem I am haveing is if I write code like this

```
 <pre class="prettyprint">
   <div class="specialForm">
   ...
 </div>
 </pre>
```

instead of rendering the text just as stack overflow does, it actually renders the DIV on the page and I have no clue what I am doing wrong

Comment: You need to escape the html like `&lt;div class=&quot;specialForm&quot;&gt;...` You can inspect your very post with Web Inspector and see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source here in stackoverflow, your post is actually:

```
&lt;pre class="prettyprint"&gt;
   &lt;div class="specialForm"&gt;
   ...
 &lt;/div&gt;
 &lt;/pre&gt;
```

This prevents the browser from treating them as html syntax and it prints literal `<`,`>` etc.